# Need help passing param at start of jenkins multijob

Tags: parameters, jenkins, tags, jobs

Can someone steer me in the right direction please?

I have a simple multijob in Jenkins. Its in 3 phases:

1. Stops the application
2. Deploys based on what tag I tell it to build from (using the List Subversion Tags option under "This build is parameterized")
3. Starts the app back up.

Doing these steps individually works fine. I can select my tag, I want to build, from the drop down and away I go. What I want to do is select the tag at the beginning of the MultiJob so that it gets passed to the correct phase and will run end to end....*stop - deploy - start*.

I tried setting the MJ up the same way that I did the deploy step but it is not getting the parameter passed to it. In the output it just says `"failed to retrieve build parameters"`.

Does anyone know how to input the tag parameter at the beginning of the MJ so that it is carried over and passed to the second phase the way I described?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multijob? Are you talking about:

- **Multi-configuration** project with multiple Axises
- Regular **free-style** project with multiple Build steps

In either case, both the free-style and the multi-configuration projects have access to build **Parameters** through use of environment variables, either *$PARAM* (Unix) or *%PARAM%* (Windows) where "PARAM" is the name of your parameter.

Re-reading your question makes me think you are talking about a job triggering **Downstream** jobs. In that case, you would need to use **[Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)** to trigger your downstream jobs. Then, under "**Add Parameters**" dropdown select "*Current build parameters*" to pass the same parameters from one job to another. Once again, you reference them as you would any other parameter through an environment variable.

Comment: Im using the Multijob plugin to create the "master" job. It has the rest of the jobs "inside" it. Like a folder with jobs in it.
I looked at how you were saying to do it with the Parameterized trigger plugin and I do have that plugin installed but I dont have an option that says "current build params" like you described.
I have Boolean, CVS Symbolic Name, Choice, File Param, Subversion tags, Password, Run, String, and Text parameters.
I feel like im missing something here.

Comment: Figured it out...
In the multijob view the Parameterized Trigger is in the Post Build section...not in the "This build is parameterized" section. This is what I was looking for.